# How to limit renderscript to specific native platforms in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, platform, renderscript

I am using Eclipse to build an Android app that uses Renderscript. I include

```
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

in my project.properties file.

Everything is running fine except that by default, Eclipse creates an apk which has a directory for all three platforms supported by Renderscript: x86, mips, armeabi-v7a. However, I am only supporting armeabi-v7a (the x86 and mips directories only contain the two .so files for Renderscript). This becomes important when publishing to the Google Play store, which uses the directories to figure out what native platform the app supports.

How do I specify that the x86 and mips platform directories should not be created?

Answer (score 0):

After your apk has been generated, you can use the zip command:

```
zip -d your.apk path_or_files_to_be_removed_inside_the_apk
```

Note that you will need to sign again your apk after altering its content.

I would strongly recommend you to migrate to Android Studio where you will find more flexibility with gradle. Eclipse is not supported officially anymore.